# Is the "Used By" Tab always empty for Pages?

Tags: where-used

Without (direct) [Page Linking](https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/page-linking), I believe Tridion Sites would never show items in the <strike>`Used By`</strike> `Used In` tab of the `Where Used` dialogue.

In other words, Pages can use other items but not vice versa.

Is this correct? Would there ever be a case where a Page is "used" in the Content Manager?

**Edit**: The tab is actually called `Used In.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “Used By” tab in the Where Used dialogue shows other items with references to the current item, but also Local Copies of the current item.

So: yes, Pages can have items in their “Used By” tab.

Comment: Ah, I almost missed local copies. I'm starting to think all of our "viewers" are related. Oh and I realize the tab is really called `Used In`. I'm not sure if I've been saying it wrong all this time or if it was ever called _Used By_.

Answer (score 5):

Another case is if a Page is added to a Bundle.

[image]